# Build cli with nestjs

Tags: nestjs, command-line-interface

I searched on web, and in the nestjs docs as well, Not able to find an example how to build cli using Nestjs,

Let me know if someone built it. or know how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Standalone Context](https://docs.nestjs.com/standalone-applications) that the doc outlines as a general way to write a one off script, or go for something more robust like [`nest-commander`](https://nest-commander.jaymcdoniel.dev). My [Ogma CLI](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma/tree/main/packages/cli) is written with `nest-commander` if you need an example.

Comment: Is there a Platform where can follow you for nestjs, Discord ?

Comment: Yep, also documented on the docs site. [NestJS Discord](https://discord.gg/nestjs)